# Disentangling ratsnest: reassigning pins

Tags: pcb-design

I've got a few digital pins that control various features of a MAX5318 DAC connected to headers. EAGLE makes a spaghetti nest out of the wiring, but I think I can make the wires not overlap each other if I reassign which pin goes to which pin on the header. Is it a worthwhile use of my time? I don't want my hard work to be wasted when I hit "ratsnest" again!

Comment: Sure, if what connects to the header is still flexible (and doesn't have harder constraints), juggling pin assignments can be in your bag of tricks for getting a cleaner layout.  That goes alongside rotate parts, juggling gate assignments, etc.  Of course remember to preserve any connector properties you care about - for example, if you have interleaved grounds, or differential signals which should be adjacent.

Comment: This is one reason many people advise you actually draw all the wires on your schematic, rather than just using labels everywhere. It might not look quite as clean, but it will give you an idea of part placement/flow and will hint how you should assign pins to the more flexible portions of your schematic like what @ChrisStratton was talking about.

Comment: That can be true, but to an extent only if you use geometrically representative schematic symbols. If schematic symbols are instead designed by function, then drawing all the wires won't necessarily help.  My personally feeling is that you should draw things to help with whatever aspect of the design is expected to be the most challenging; if it's understanding function, draw abstract functional schematics, while if it's hand routing on one or two layers, draw physically representative.

Answer (score 1):

It's a normal practice to streamline the layout by changing the connections between nets and GPIO pins on μC, where appropriate.  It's usually worthwhile.

MAX5318 has an SPI interface.  Usually, the hardware SPI is available only on specific μC pins.  Similar thing with interrupt inputs.  This limits your connection options for such signals.